# Single audit failure causes review ban?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

See [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7280022)

This is the first review of *any* type I have failed in months, and was actually the result of a misplaced click.

Is it really necessary to ban someone with generally excellent review statistics over one single error?

When I first started reviewing, and when the quality of audits was much worse than it is, I "failed" several per month and never saw a ban. Has that changed?

Comment: The automated bans are never applied just for a single failure. Rather, audit failures in the past 30 days are taken into account.

Comment: It is possible for a moderator to give you a *manual* review ban, but these days that usually involves a custom message. This often happens if they found spam having been approved via a review queue; the moderator will seek out all that approved the spam and give them a band to send a strong signal that they should be paying more attention to keep spam out.

Comment: I think attempting to delete a good answer is a much more serious thing than not deleting a bad answer :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: More serious, perhaps, but serious enough to warrant review banning on the strength of a *single* failure? I think not. The audit system isn't reliable enough for that, and frankly I don't see the need for quite such high standards for reviewers; one-off errors are not the problem — low standards are the problem. Specifically standards low enough to simply click the same button repeatedly, which is the problem audits were originally created to solve, but to a lesser extent general patterns of incompetence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All failed audits within the past 60 days are examined by the system when determining whether to impose a temporary review ban after an audit is failed, along with other aspects of your review history.

You previously failed this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6813374

In both cases, you voted to delete answers that were generally accepted as useful in answering the question.

Comment: So two failed audits in 60 days causes a ban on ALL reviewing ability?  That seems rather harsh.