# Why did I get banned from reviewing after failing one audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, review-suspension

I know here are questions about this, but I only found ones from people who have failed recently or been banned before.

I just got banned *for the first time* from reviewing because I failed an audit. I do not dispute that I reviewed it incorrectly, but I don't understand why this particular failure resulted in a ban.

I have failed reviews before, but not in a long time. Despite [what I just answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333048/812786) I decided to bite the bullet and clicked through all the non-skipped reviews in the first two pages of my history for that queue (going back over a month, to Jul 14). Results: 1 failed audit (the one that just got me banned), and... 8 passed audits.

What?

Comment: [How many incorrect reviews will cause banning?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271233/839601)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195099

Comment: @gnat, from that link: "you can't get banned for failing one audit" and "scales based on your past within a 30-day window since your last failure", so... still confused.

Comment: @KeithM, from that link: "seems the number of failed audits I've had in the past month is two", which doesn't apply to me. So I guess what I'm looking for here is either "a mod set the ban for x" or "you must have triggered the heuristic on x".

Comment: Did you get banned immediately after failing the audit by a message there, or did the ban show up a bit later?

Comment: @NathanTuggy immediately after failing

Comment: Did the audit you failed turn out to be spam?

Comment: @BSMP no, it had been deleted as Link-Only, and I selected "No Action Needed". (I thought it might have enough context, apparently I was wrong)

Comment: So I didn't think auto-bans for one failed audit w/in 30 days were supposed to happen, based on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-ban-progressive-system/256234#256234), [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271233/812786), [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban/190562#190562), etc. But I checked my history again and I failed another audit Jun 27, which is just inside a *60 day window*, described [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287678/812786). Mystery solved.