# Is there now a two-month review ban period?

Tags: support, review-suspension

Until now, from my experience, the review ban sequence was something like this:

1. Warning
2. 1 day
3. 1 week
4. 1 month
5. Reset: go to step 1

However, after being banned for one month, I failed a review audit:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14418134.
>
> Come back on Jan 26 '17 at 11:29 to continue reviewing.

Now it seems I am banned for **two months**.

Did the ban sequence rules change? I was not able to find any information. Is there a new sequence description available somewhere?

This is not a duplicate of [Single audit failure causes review ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287660/single-audit-failure-causes-review-ban), as I am asking only about the two-month period for the ban, instead of the expected one month. It is not about being banned after a single audit failure.

Comment: Moderator imposed ban? Check your messages/email?

Comment: It was not by moderator, there is specific question linked to my ban, which i failed to review correctly. Regarding duplicate - my main point was about 2 months period because it is the first time i see it. Used to be one month max for ages.

Comment: @VojtechRuzicka why do you not think it was a moderator?  Generally speaking, when you have a review ban that is not following the posted guidelines, it was a moderator.

Comment: No, I clicked to edit an answer. Then it said. "Stop! Look and listen! This was just a test to check you were paying attention. This question was supposed to be deleted instead of edited. You are banned until Jan 26th. 2017"

Comment: Why would the ban reset to only a warning after a one month ban? That doesn't make sense?

Comment: @ModusTollens It used to reset, this is how the system used to behave. I experienced it several times already.

Comment: @ModusTollens the system is/was designed in such a way that your failures over the last 60 days are taken into account.  Once you hit the one month ban, you're given a (somewhat) clean slate to show you've improved your reviewing.

Comment: So, uh, if I keep on failing in reviews queue long enough I'll be kind of get "rewarded" by a reset? Ok...

Comment: @ModusTollens not saying  I agree with it, just saying that is how the system is designed.  But everyone probably does deserve a 2nd chance.  However, people who habitually fail audits, and have already gotten a 2nd, 3rd, or 4th chance probably do need longer bans, and it looks like this has been implemented now

Comment: I am curious was edit you had planned for that answer, because for the life of me I can't imagine any sort of edit would make that answer not suck?

Comment: I am not claiming it was unjust, I was really interested in the changed mechanics of ban duration.

Comment: @ModusTollens It wasn't added by design, per say.  The ban for an audit is longer than normal if you have been banned in the past month (to prevent someone from getting an increased ban because they failed a few audits like half a year ago.  After a month long ban, you'll never have been banned in the past month, so you'll always get the first tier of ban.  Clearly they decided to improve the logic behind this process (likely making it so that the ban tiers reset after a month *since the end of your last ban* or something else more sensible like that.

Comment: You should be really concerned about how you review if you have been banned enough to notice a change in ban duration.

Comment: Yes there is. If you get banned again within 30 days of your last ban, the duration will now double, and there is no cap.

Comment: Instead of complaining about the ban period, have you considered **not making** [unnecessary](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27101527/4) or [actively](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40847182/2) [harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40836823/2) edits?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Exactly my first thought when I read "from my experience"

Comment: Take the two months to study the guidelines on how to review. Getting banned from reviewing doesn't happen by accident, but by not following the rules occasionally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single audit failure causes review ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287660/single-audit-failure-causes-review-ban)

Comment: @ssube, baao - after Mark Rotteveel already raised this topic once (and that was **also** after the OP made clear the intention of the question) ...were your comments really that constructive? Or maybe you even now feel that a fourth person should come here and **again** share "useful pedagogical instructions" with the OP? And then there should come more people and upvote all such comments? He just asked and is now being hit. I'm really wondering why is such gang action necessary? And why is it stereotypical for so many people. Did he harm you personally or what is the matter with you people..

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Based on [Review bans should escalate beyond 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days), which was a feature requested by a Stack Overflow moderator, the developers just added longer bans, both for automatic suspensions and manually mod suspensions.

To quote the relevant points from [bluefeet's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days/287296#287296)

> ...Not only can you hand out longer bans, we've also adjusted the way automatic bans are handed out to users who fail audits. When calculating the automatic length of the ban, we check to see when the last ban ended and determine the new length based on the following requirements:
>
> - If the time since the last ban ended is less than or equal to 30 days, then the new ban is double the length of the last one. This is not capped, meaning if the last ban was for 365 days, then the new one is 730.
> - If the time since the last ban ended is greater than 30 days, then the new ban is half the length of the last ban or 2 days - whichever is greater.
>
> This should help with reviewers who continually fail audits and need extended time away from reviewing. It also allows moderators to 'reset' the ban length by handing out a ban of any length, which would then be used by the automatic calculation of time-off.

Since you seem to be well versed in the traditional cycle that ended with a 30-day review ban, you have a significant history of audit failures within the last 30 days, so the system instituted a longer ban for you (basically doubling of the 30-day ban).  This also means that when you come back from reviewing, if you trigger another review ban in the next 30 days, it will be 120 days since your current one is 60-days.

---

This new mechanism [completely replaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days/287296#comment932671_287296) the old one, so this means the old cycle of `2 -> 7 -> 30 days -> reset` is gone.  Instead it is replaced by a new neverending one (assuming you keep failing within 30 days of getting the review privileges back: `2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 16 -> 32 -> 64 -> 128 days ->....`.

This new mechanism grows more slowly (assuming a mod doesn't manually apply a longer ban at any point in the cycle) taking 5 bans to reach a month long review ban, but is much harsher otherwise since the window between failures is longer and doesn't max out or reset.

The second bullet in bluefeet's answer is also very relevant ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days/287296#comment932791_287296)). There is no timed "get out of jail free card" on your suspension length. If you were banned from reviewing, and it was more than 30 days ago, your next suspension period will be half of the previous, regardless of when that previous suspension was (so your review history today could have an impact on an suspension 12 months from now). An extended period of good reviews won't completely erase the poor review history you have, so it is important to try to learn from your mistakes as early as possible to avoid getting into a deep trap of long bans that may be difficult to recover from.

Comment: Almost feels like they had this OP in mind when they designed the feature ...

Comment: Well, it is not like I am trying to ruin the site or anything, it is just really easy to do one incorrect review in hundreds of others, when you review every day many queues.

Comment: @VojtechRuzicka problem is that poor reviewers, even when you are trying to be helpful, can be harmful because it leaves posts improperly handled or allows spam to hang around.  Review audits, while having problems with bad audit selection, are usually pretty easy when you are taking your time. You need to learn from your past mistakes and try to improve.  With this new feature, a couple more review bans and you'll be banned for over a year (60 days -> 120 days -> 240 days -> 480 days...).

Comment: I get that. However, I was unable to find any info on deescalation, except for after 30 days, ban will be the half. Does it mean this happens every 30 days to a minumum of 2 days? Or it just stays at half?

Comment: The way i read it is beyond 30 days, it will be half, so that means 90 days later, it will still be half of the previous ban.  Don't see any mention of a time when that "half" would expire. But you can leave a comment on bluefeet's answer, and ask her

Comment: @VojtechRuzicka You didn't do "one incorrect review in hundreds of others". You did a fairly large number of incorrect reviews, as you've described in your question. I've been review-banned two or three times over the years after failing a few audits. Not all audits were "good" audits IMHO, but most were, and I took it as a lesson. That's sort of the point of it. Reviewing can be harder than it appears at first sight and is something of a skill that needs to be learned.

Comment: I mean since the last ban. Nevertheless, I agree with you and I did not want to sound like I am trying to say I do not deserve the penalty. That would be off-topic from the original question's point, which was just making sure what are the new mechanics for bans.

Comment: what @Carpetsmoker said is spot on. To me audit failures have been _extremely_ helpful in bringing me back to being attentive when I have been loosing focus. I had no review suspensions but that's maybe because every audit failure brought me back to being firmly focused and attentive when reviewing

Comment: @VojtechRuzicka if you failed one audit (since your most recent ban), this also suggests, by the law of averages, that you also did quite a few other low-quality or even counter-productive reviews, which just didn't happen to be audits.

Comment: Probably unintended consequences, but someone who wanted to could game the system to deescalate a long review ban by taking an extended voluntary hiatus and then deliberately failing audits 31 days after a ban ends.  Eg get a 60day ban, initially ignore the review queue after the ban expires and then intentionally fail audits 91 days after the ban was applied later which is more than 30 since the old one ended, and would result in only a 30 day ban.  Then 61 days later fail another bunch of audits to ratchet down to a 15 day ban and repeat.

Comment: @DanNeely true, but how many people actually game the system in that way?  Most of the "abuse" is people reviewing as much as possible as quickly as possible to get the badges, so taking voluntary leaves for that long to ratchet down the ban duration seems to be contrary to that motivation.  And even still, it more or less accomplishes the same goal - the bad reviewer isn't actually reviewing and causing harm to the site,

Comment: @psubsee2003 mostly that not allowing it to slowly deescalate on its own and allowing a user to game the system and unwind it are somewhat at cross purposes.

Comment: @DanNeely true, someone could intentionally unwind the ban slowly, but depending on how deep the hole it, it would take a lot of work that could be spent learning to review better.  I see your point, but I don't see as a significant issue because someone who is a bad reviewer that unwinds it intentionally is taking off from reviewing to unwind it (which accomplishes the same thing as a review suspension).  And if someone who learned how to review well unwinds it, well probably not a big deal.  But if you feel strongly enough about this issue, best to raise it as a new meta question.

Comment: `If you were banned from reviewing, and it was more than 30 days ago, your next suspension period will be half of the previous` the "it was more than 30 days ago" is starting from the day you got unbanned, or the day of the ban?

Comment: @AndréPaulo per the quoted section from the linked post, it is based on when the ban ends.

Comment: @eoredson more or less.  If you fail your first audit immediately after getting unbanned, then yes, that would be your total time banned.  But that assumes that the data type in the SQL server that holds the ban length allows the number to get that larger.  That also assumes the first ban is only 1 day long and I am not certain that is the case,

Comment: @eoredson the point is why add complexity when it isn't needed.  When someone is that bad a of a reviewer, they need a lifetime ban, so this essentially accomplishes that.  If someone has failed that many times to get banned that many times, it seems that they won't learn from their mistakes so letting the ban time accure more slowly won't fix much.  And for the rare case that someone has had a lot of really bad luck with poor audits, it is fixable with moderator intervention and/or the user just winding the ban down themselves by not getting banned within 30 days of the previous ban